# About using Bob Jenkins' perfect hash library

Tags: hash

When i use Bob Jenkins's perfect hash package, After build "perfect" binary, i could not even pass the example by "./perfect < sample_input" , it always warn me that "fatal error: Cannot perfect hash: cannot build tab[]", Has anyone met this issue before ? Are there any other steady perfect hash concerned library or package, Thanks in advanced!
Quote Jenkins' perfect hash library link as below:
http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with gcc and clang under 64 bit Linux and found the reason:
The type definitions of the 4 byte types `ub4` and `sb4` must be changed in standard.h from

```
typedef unsigned long int ub4;
typedef signed long int sb4;
```

to

```
typedef unsigned int ub4;
typedef signed int sb4;
```

or might be defined as aliases to types from stdint.h (`uint32_t` and `int32_t`).